# Pointers and pointers to 2-D array

Tags: c

I was browsing a question and found this answer.

I couldnt understand this program at the end of the answer,
Specifically the first three lines of the putoff function

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 #define NUM_ELEM(ar) (sizeof(ar) / sizeof((ar)[0]))

int * put_off(const int newrow[2])
{
static int mymatrix[3][2];
static int (*rowp)[2] = mymatrix;
int (* const border)[] = mymatrix + NUM_ELEM(mymatrix);

memcpy(rowp, newrow, sizeof(*rowp));
rowp += 1;
if (rowp == border) {
    rowp = mymatrix;
}

return *rowp;
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i = 0;
int row[2] = {0, 1};
int *rout;

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    row[0] = i;
    row[1] += i;
    rout = put_off(row);
    printf("%d (%p): [%d, %d]\n", i, (void *) rout, rout[0], rout[1]);
}

return 0;
  }
```

I need some help with the first 3 lines in the function in the program.

Comment: Please don't make us go through a link.  Write a complete, self-contained question.

Comment: And please tell exactly what you think you dont understand. Most probably we won't see the erason for confusion.

Comment: The first three lines? Of the file? Of main? Of put_off?

Comment: @RyanAmos- Of the putoff function.

Comment: @JayK: Maybe you are not aware of this, but:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq  => "What kind of questions should I not ask here?" "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."  If you don't see that you've just asked an open ended question, I don't know what I can do for you.  So you don't understand XYZ? What do you want me to do about it? There are many ways to misunderstand.  I don't generally understand the poet Emily Dickenson.  So?

Comment: If you don't understand `static int mymatrix[3][2];`, don't bother with trying to understand the next two lines.  The next two lines declare pointers to arrays of `int` with two elements.  The first is initialized to `mymatrix` (the zeroth row of `mymatrix`); the second is initialized to one matrix beyond the end of `mymatrix`.

Comment: @JayC- I apologize for posting such a question. Is there a way to delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some explanatory notes to get you going:

```
static int mymatrix[3][2];
```

`mymatrix` is a 2D array of ints with 3 rows and 2 columns.  C uses row-major order, meaning the rows are stored one after the other in memory.  The static keyword makes its values persistent across function calls (while the scope is still local).

```
static int (*rowp)[2] = mymatrix;
```

This declares a pointer to array of two integers (i.e., a row of mymatrix in this case).  Initializing it to mymatrix is the equivalent of initializing it to the first row.  The static keyword of course means the same as above.

```
int (* const border)[] = mymatrix + NUM_ELEM(mymatrix);
```

`border` is a constant pointer (i.e., the pointer can't be changed) to an array of ints.  It is initialized to a memory address beyond mymatrix (which is maybe a tad unusual).  Specifically, it points to the next row that would exist if `mymatrix` had one more row, so when the row pointer points to exactly that spot, the function wraps around the row pointer back to the first row having filled the entire matrix.

For conglomerations of pointers, arrays parentheses, etc., you can always try [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) to see if it can translate it for you.